# Amplify custom configuration error on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm trying to integrate Amplify to my project but I'm having some issues with the configuration.
The backend is sending the S3 Storage configuration to my project so I have to configurate Amplify with the data received.
I tried to configurate the storage following [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/blob/main/AmplifyPlugins/Storage/AWSS3StoragePluginFunctionalTests/AWSS3StoragePluginConfigurationTests.swift) test but It's failing with the following error:

```
PluginError: Unable to decode configuration
Recovery suggestion: Make sure the plugin configuration is JSONValue
  ▿ pluginConfigurationError : 3 elements
    - .0 : "Unable to decode configuration"
    - .1 : "Make sure the plugin configuration is JSONValue"
    - .2 : nil
```

This is my code:

```
func amplifyConfigure() {        
        do {
            Amplify.Logging.logLevel = .verbose
            
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSS3StoragePlugin())

            let storageConfiguration = StorageCategoryConfiguration(
                        plugins: [
                            "awsS3StoragePlugin": [
                                "bucket": "bucket",
                                "region": "us-west-2",
                                "defaultAccessLevel": "protected"
                            ]
                        ]
                    )
            
            let amplifyConfiguration = AmplifyConfiguration(storage: storageConfiguration)
            try Amplify.configure(amplifyConfiguration)
            
            // LOG success.
        } catch {
            // LOG Error.
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me with this custom configuration?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that config cannot be declared directly in one go for some reason, possibly type-related. For me it works if I declare it in multiple steps. Try replacing this:

```
let storageConfiguration = StorageCategoryConfiguration(
                        plugins: [
                            "awsS3StoragePlugin": [
                                "bucket": "bucket",
                                "region": "us-west-2",
                                "defaultAccessLevel": "protected"
                            ]
                        ]
                    )
```

with this:

```
var storageConfigurationJson : [String:JSONValue] = [ "awsS3StoragePlugin" : [] ]
storageConfigurationJson["awsS3StoragePlugin"] = ["bucket": "bucket",
                                                  "region": "us-west-2",
                                                  "defaultAccessLevel": "protected"]
let storageConfiguration = StorageCategoryConfiguration(plugins: storageConfigurationJson)
```

I've only used Amplify config with `AuthCategoryConfiguration`, so in case `StorageCategoryConfiguration` has a different syntax you may need to adjust my suggested code accordingly.